# Dash Choosing an ID and then Make Plot with Slider

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a dataset which is similar to below one.
Please note that there are multiple values for an ID.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME':pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-05 23:00:00',freq='h'),
                   'SBP':[random.uniform(110, 160) for n in range(120)],
                   'DBP':[random.uniform(60, 100) for n in range(120)],
                   'ID':[random.randrange(1, 100) for n in range(120)],
                   'TIMEINTERVAL':[random.randrange(1, 200) for n in range(120)]})

df['VISIT'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.day

df['MODE'] = np.select([df['VISIT']==1, df['VISIT'].isin([2,3])], ['CKD', 'Dialysis'], 'Late TPL')
```

I would like to use Dash so that I can firstly choose the ID, and then make a plot of that chosen ID. Besides, I made a slider to choose the time interval between measurements in terms of minutes.

My issue is that I could not implement both slider and choosing ID in Dash. How can I integrate the following function into my Dash code? Alternatively, how can I choose the ID fist and then make plot out of it?

```
# function to choose ID
def choose_id(dataframe_name, id_number):
    return dataframe_name[dataframe_name['ID']==id_number]
#patient = choose_id(df, 9)
```

I use the following DASH code to make slider:

```
app = Dash(__name__)


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H4('Interactive Scatter Plot with ABPM dataset'),
    dcc.Graph(id="scatter-plot"),
    html.P("Filter by time interval:"),
    dcc.Dropdown(df.ID.unique(), id='pandas-dropdown-1'), # for choosing ID,
    dcc.RangeSlider(
        id='range-slider',
        min=0, max=600, step=10,
        marks={0: '0', 50: '50', 100: '100', 150: '150', 200: '200', 250: '250', 300: '300', 350: '350', 400: '400', 450: '450', 500: '500', 550: '550', 600: '600'},
        value=[0, 600]
    ),
    html.Div(id='dd-output-container')
])


@app.callback(
    Output("dd-output-container", "children"),
    Output("scatter-plot", "figure"),
    Input("pandas-dropdown-1", "value"),
    Input("range-slider", "value"))

def update_bar_chart(value,slider_range):
    patient = choose_patient(df, value)
    df = patient 
    low, high = slider_range
    mask = (df['TIMEINTERVAL'] > low) & (df['TIMEINTERVAL'] < high)
    fig = px.scatter(
        df[mask], x="DATE_TIME", y=["SBP","DBP"],
        hover_data=['TIMEINTERVAL'],facet_col='VISIT',
         facet_col_wrap=2,
         symbol='MODE')
    fig.update_xaxes(matches=None,
                     showticklabels=True)

    return fig


app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I get this error Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Users\oezmenma\dashv1\dash2_choose_patient.py", line 63, in
> update_bar_chart
> mask = (df['TIMEINTERVAL'] > low) & (df['TIMEINTERVAL'] < high) TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried debugging it and just looking what the dtypes of the arguments are?

Comment: @maxxel_  the value of pandas-dropdown-1 is an integer. That means I should choose ID using chosing_ID function. Hence, I edited the question in update_bar_chart function.      ID = choose_id(df, value)

Comment: I tried to reproduce your program to solve the problem, but there is no TIMEINTERVAL column in the provided dataframe?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Hamzah  I just fixed it.

Comment: @dspractician ohh i think i see it now. instead of creating a mask you should just use pandas .loc method. so basically you ditch the mask and for df[mask] you put a df.loc[(df['TIMEINTERVAL'] > low) & (df['TIMEINTERVAL'] < high)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the corrected version below, I fixed multiple issues.

```
app = Dash(__name__)


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H4('Interactive Scatter Plot with ABPM dataset'),
    dcc.Graph(id="scatter-plot"),
    html.P("Filter by time interval:"),
    dcc.Dropdown(df.ID.unique(), id='pandas-dropdown-1'), # for choosing ID,
    dcc.RangeSlider(
        id='range-slider',
        min=0, max=600, step=10,
        marks={0: '0', 50: '50', 100: '100', 150: '150', 200: '200', 250: '250', 300: '300', 350: '350', 400: '400', 450: '450', 500: '500', 550: '550', 600: '600'},
        value=[0, 600]
    ),
    html.Div(id='dd-output-container')
])


@app.callback(
    Output("scatter-plot", "figure"),
    Input("pandas-dropdown-1", "value"),
    Input("range-slider", "value"),
    prevent_initial_call=True)

def update_bar_chart(value,slider_range):
    low, high = slider_range
    df1 = df.query("ID == @value & TIMEINTERVAL > @low & TIMEINTERVAL < @high").copy() 
    
    if df1.shape[0] != 0:
        fig = px.scatter(df1, x="DATE_TIME", y=["SBP","DBP"],
                         hover_data=['TIMEINTERVAL'],facet_col='VISIT',
                         facet_col_wrap=2,
                         symbol='MODE')
        
        fig.update_xaxes(matches= None, showticklabels=True)

        return fig
    else: 
        return dash.no_update


app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: can you explain briefly what this code does? df1 = df.query It is my first time to see the @ signs.  I cannot write the code because of @ signs

Comment: Instead of writing `df[ (df['ID'] == value) & (df['TIMEINTERVAL '] > low) & (df['TIMEINTERVAL ']  < high) ]`, I used the query function.

Comment: If I use df.query(" ID == value"), python will interpret the `value` as a column, therefore I use @ to interpret it as an external variable not in the dataframe.

Comment: Please read more about query here: https://dataindependent.com/pandas/pandas-query-filter-data-df-query/